# Dependencies In Same Reactor

Tags: tycho

I have a very simple Tycho reactor with two modules: one is a standard Maven project with this addition to make it a bundle:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-bundle</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>org.acme.jar</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The second is a Tycho project that has a dependency to the above JAR in the *MANIFEST.MF*.

If I start the build, I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: plugin 0.0.1.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: plugin 0.0.1.qualifier requires 'bundle org.acme.jar 0.0.1' but it could not be found
```

Which is really weird, because the bundle **is** in the same reactor.

But no worries, I can just add the Maven dependency, too:

```
<!-- parent pom.xml -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>0.26.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
    </configuration>
</plugin> 

<!-- plug-in pom.xml -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Still I get the same exception, which is weird because the [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#.22POM_dependencies_consider.22) claims: *Maven resolves the GAV dependencies according to the normal Maven rules.*

That's just not true. Evidently `org.acme.jar` doesn't get resolved. Or maybe Tycho fails to see that it's a bundle.

The JAR module is an API project used for server side components, and we want to drop SWT / Tycho in the long run, so it's not an option to make `org.acme.jar` an Eclipse plug-in.

How do I define dependencies in the same reactor for Tycho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid that what you ask for is currently not possible. The Tycho Wiki documents [this limitation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts#It_is_not_possible_to_mix_pom-first_and_manifest-first_projects_in_the_same_reactor_build.) in the [dependency on pom-first artifacts HOW-TO](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts).

That being said, if you really want your whole build (`maven-bundle-plugin` and Tycho parts) to run with a single `mvn clean install`, then using the [`maven-invoker-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) at the end of the “plain Maven” build to fork a “Tycho build” should work. It’s a rather cumbersome workaround, however ([example on Github](https://github.com/codetrails/ctrlflow-aer-client/tree/master/repositories/p2-repository-invoker)).